# Ruby in Rails, destroy does not work in edit. routing to show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, edit, destroy

I have a problem with the destroy action.
It works in the index.html.erb very fine.
But I can't get it work in the edit.html.erb
It routes to the show even without asking for a permission.

Many solutions here say it has something to do with jQuery. Well as you can see, I tried all I could find.

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
    <!--Delete Problem in Edit-->
    <%#= javascript_include_tag :all %>
    <%#= javascript_include_tag :application %>
    <%#= javascript_include_tag :default %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

Is there a solution that works for my situation?

This is my delete button in edit:

```
<%= content_tag(:a, :href => contact_path(@contact), :class => "btn btn-warning pull-right", :style => "margin:0; margin-right:15px;", confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete) do %>
<%= t "list.button_delete" %>
        <%#= link_to I18n.t(".list.delete"), contact, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %>
        <%#= link_to 'delete', contact_path(@contact), :method => :delete %>
<% end %>
```

I tried many things, as well.

The following is the action:

```
def destroy
    #@contact = Contact.find(params[:id])
    @contact = current_user.contacts.find(params[:id])
    @contact.destroy
    redirect_to contacts_url,
                            alert: 'Successfully deleted the contact'
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
<%= content_tag(:a, :href => contact_path(@contact), :class => "btn btn-warning pull-right", :style => "margin:0; margin-right:15px;", confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete) do %>
```

with

```
<%= content_tag(:a, :href => contact_path(@contact), :class => "btn btn-warning pull-right", :style => "margin:0; margin-right:15px;", data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}, data: {method: :delete}) do %>
```

It should be `data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'}` instead of `confirm: 'Are you sure?'` and also `data: {method: :delete}` instead of `method: :delete` .

where, `link_to` method interpolates `confirm: 'Are you sure?'` as `data-confirm="Are you sure?"` and `method: :delete` as `data-method="delete"`.

BUT `content_tag` method interpolates `confirm: 'Are you sure?'` as `confirm="Are you sure?"` and `method: :delete` as `method="delete"` so your javascript call is not getting invoked.

Comment: I don't understand the outcoming data-method in HTML, but it works. Thank you. :)

Comment: @Lintu check how `data-*` works here [link](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp). Try the examples given on that page.

Answer (score 1):

In your `destroy` action replace:

```
@contact = current_user.contacts.find(params[:id])
```

with:

```
@contact = @current_user.contacts.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: Unfortunitely it does not work.
It still routes to show, without asking
And the delete from the index, which has the same action has an error message:

undefined method `contacts' for nil:NilClass

Comment: post your routes file. Also apparently `current_user` variable is `nil`. Where do you assign it?

Comment: root :to => 'contacts#index'
devise_for :users
resources :contacts

Comment: I assign them to each other with: user has many and contacts has one
contacts model:
belongs_to :user
user model:
has_many :contacts

Comment: @Lintu this is your only route? If so then you need to add a route for the `destroy` action as well. As for the `current_user` variable, it must be assigned inside the controller action you are using it.

Comment: I thoug I had a route for the delete method:  contact GET    /contacts/:id(.:format)        contacts#show
         PUT    /contacts/:id(.:format)        contacts#update
         DELETE /contacts/:id(.:format)        contacts#destroy
Or I misunderstand you.

Comment: Please paste the whole code of the routes and the controller. It's hard to help you otherwise.